# Time and memory limit exceeded - Python3 - Number Theory

Tags: python-3.x, numbers, runtime-error, number-theory

I am trying to find the sum of the multiples of 3 or 5 of all the numbers upto N.

This is a practise question on HackerEarth. I was able to pass all the test cases except 1. I get a time and memory exceeded error. I looked up the documentation and learnt that **int** can handle large numbers and the type **bignum** was removed.

I am still learning python and would appreciate any constructive feedback.

Could you please point me in the right direction so I can optimise the code myself?

```
test_cases = int(input())
for i in range(test_cases):
    user_input = int(input())
    sum = 0
    for j in range (0, user_input):
        if j % 3 == 0:
            sum = sum + j
        elif j % 5 == 0:
            sum = sum + j
    print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

In such problems, try to use some math to find a direct solution rather than brute-forcing it.

You can calculate the number of multiples of k less than n, and calculate the sum of the multiples.

For example, with k=3 and n=13, you have 13 // 3 = 4 multiples.
The sum of these 4 multiples of 3 is 3*1 + 3*2 + 3*3 + 3*4 = 3 * (1+2+3+4)

Then, use the relation: 1+2+....+n = n*(n+1)/2

To sum the multiples of 3 and 5, you can sum the multiples of 3, add the sum of the multiples of 5, and subtract the ones you counted twice: the multiples of 15.

So, you could do it like this:

```
def sum_of_multiples_of(k, n):
    """
    Returns the sum of the multiples of k under n
    """
    # number of multiples of k between 1 and n
    m = n // k
    return k * m * (m+1) // 2

def sum_under(n):
    return (sum_of_multiples_of(3, n)
           + sum_of_multiples_of(5, n)
           - sum_of_multiples_of(15, n))

# 3+5+6+9+10 = 33
print(sum_under(10))
# 33

# 3+5+6+9+10+12+15+18 = 78
print(sum_under(19))
# 78
```